# Swift 3 Variable self-removes

Tags: swift3

I have very-very strange things. 
In my simple function I create variable which contains dictionary of settings parameters. It is set as 'let', so inner loop just reads it. 
In a random moment of loop time it crashes with "unresolved settings". 
It seems like smth makes it nil. Who does it?

```
private static func preferencesFilter(userIDs: [Int], access: String) -> [User] {
    self.sharedInstance.delegate?.updateActionLabel(label: "Filter")
    var result = [VKUser]()
    let settings = self.parseSettings()
    let progressFraction = 1.00 / Float(userIDs.count)
    var n = 0
    for userID in userIDs {
        if sharedInstance.stopped {
            return []
        }
        n += 1
        let user = VKUser.getUser(id: userID, access_token: access_token)
        if settings["gender"] != nil {
            if user.sex == settings["gender"] as! String {
                if (user.born?.isBetweeen(date1: settings["minAge"] as! Date, date2: settings["maxAge"] as! Date))! {
                    if settings["country"] != nil {
                        if user.country == settings["country"] as! String {
                            result.append(user)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        result.append(user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (user.born?.isBetweeen(date1: settings["minAge"] as! Date, date2: settings["maxAge"] as! Date))! {
                if settings["country"] != nil {
                    if user.country == settings["country"] as! String {
                        result.append(user)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    result.append(user)
                }
            }
        }
        self.sharedInstance.delegate?.updateProgress(value: Float(n) * progressFraction)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: I think you really wrote quite some unsafe code. Try adding some "if let" combinations or "guards" to make it safer. Try not to force cast anything (with the "!"), it will crash your program eventually. 
I tried to rewrite it into something more swiftlike and safer, but even then got lost in all the if-else statements and skipped cases. Did you write any unit tests to check if this method is doing the things you want it to? There is a lot of combinations that will or won't append a user.

Comment: @Jelle thank you for your answer! Do you mean that smth is wrong with this dictionary? But how it can be wrong if it is static. It just loads to memory (as I understand correctly). I do not update it dynamically. Is it smth "garbage collector" wrong work? 'cos if I will do "guards", it would just mean that it is no error and script is working not correctly.

Comment: What I mean is that the code is hard to read and likely to crash in real situations. I'll try to rewrite it into something more stable... hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code into something more swift like:

```
private static func preferencesFilter(userIDs: [Int], access_token: String) -> [User]? {
    guard userIDs.count > 0 else {
        return [User]() // no input, return empty list
    }
    let settings = self.parseSettings()
    guard let minAge = settings["minAge"] as? Date,
        let maxAge = settings["maxAge"] as? Date
        else {
            return nil
    }
    let country = settings["country"] as? String    // specified or nil
    let gender = settings["gender"] as? String      // specified or nil

    sharedInstance.delegate?.updateActionLabel(label: "Filter")
    var result = [VKUser]()
    let progressFraction = 1.00 / Float(userIDs.count)
    var n = 0
    for userID in userIDs {
        if !sharedInstance.stopped {
            n += 1
            let user = VKUser.getUser(id: userID, access_token: access_token)
            var shouldInclude = true

            if user.sex != gender { // wrong sex or no required gender specified
                shouldInclude = false
            }
            if user.country != country { // wrong country or no required country specified
                shouldInclude = false
            }
            if let born = user.born {
                if !born.isBetweeen(date1: minAge, date2: maxAge) {
                    shouldInclude = false
                }
            } else { // no user.born date, cant check if in range
                shouldInclude = false
            }

            if shouldInclude {
                result.append(user)
            }
            sharedInstance.delegate?.updateProgress(value: Float(n) * progressFraction)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Is that what you intended to write? How is that running for you?
Can you change this into a non-static method? Makes more sense to me.
You can see it returns an optional now, since the method might fail with a nil. Your calling code should handle that correctly.

Comment: It works! In fact, I see it really simpler and easier to read, but the reason why my "dirty" edition crashes is unknown to me. Here we just check for nil, does it mean that in some cases it may be nilled and we won't see it happened? And if we do not unwrap it hardly, we just loose some data?

Comment: It took me a while to decipher your code, so it was likely to contain some funny hidden errors. To examine the real problem I'd need to run the real code and debug it. Perhaps there are side effects in the delegate that are solved now. Perhaps something else was wrong. At least now the code is easy to read and understand, so spotting errors should be easier as well. 
There are several ways how nil values are handled in this code: some required non-optionals (minAge and maxAge from settings), some real optionals that are ignored if they are nil (country, sex) and an optional "born" property.

Comment: Some minor remarks: I'd change the minAge and maxAge into better names, because they are not "age" values, but dates. Also "born" is not quite the name I'd use,  birthdate could be better. And gender and sex might be easier to read when they are both "gender".

Comment: Unfortunately, it still not working. It just skips checks. On every 15 element settings becomes "nothing". By the way, this func works on global queue, does it matter?

Comment: can you comment out the calls to the delegate and see if that helps? Is this running on a separate thread?

Comment: the same problem. I have similar func without checks that works. 
Can it be smth like "memory-leak"? Is it any way to debug it?